# Add local repository in specific folder of GIT server repo

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I'm migrating code from SVN to GIT using SubGit.
Some of my SVN repositories are built as:

```
SVN-Repo
    + Project1
        + trunk
        + branches
        + tags
    + Project2
        + trunk
        + branches
        + tags
```

Using SubGit:

```
subgit import --svn-url <svn_server>/SVN-Repo/Project1 C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\Project1.git --username xxx --password xxx.
```

After what I clone in a local repo.

Then:

```
git clone <Git_server>/_git/GIT-Repo
git push -u origin --all
```

The result is that in GIT-Repo at the end I don' have a folder named Project1 like I had with SVN.
After investigation I dind't find  the command allowing me to create this Proejct1 folder GIT repo.

Could you pelase help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What result do you want to achieve (I don't understand "git clone" + "git push" commands)? The commands you used created a Git repository at `C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\Project1.git` Isn't that what you want? You need not setup a Git server to serve Project1.git

Comment: I would like to have the same structure in GIT than in SVN. Meaning inside GIT repo: 2 sub-folders Project1 and Project2 with master... Because when I push Project1, then it's located at the root of the repo and not in a folder named Project1

Comment: This is how Git works: a repository consists of branches, a branch has a tree (folder) that has it's own subtrees and so on. A branch cannot be contained inside a subtree. But there's a way to translate the whole your repository with 2 projects as a directory (not recommended) or to a repository with branches `refs/heads/<repo>/*` or `refs/heads/<repo>-*` branchnames (this also doesn't make sense if the projects are not related). So what you did, was the most reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

There're 3 options

**Option 1.** What you already did (the most reasonable option).
Convert both projects in SVN into 2 separate Git repositories.
Then setup access to the repositories using GitLab, Atlassian Bitbucket Server, or any other Git server software.

**Option 2.** Treat the whole SVN repository as a single directory.

```
subgit configure --svn-url <svn_server>/SVN-Repo --layout directory C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\repo.git

subgit install C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\repo.git
```

Then you can run

```
subgit uninstall C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\repo.git
```

if you don't need continuous synchronization. In this case the Git repository will be rooted at SVN-Repo.

**Option 3.** One Git repository with branches from both projects.

```
subgit configure --svn-url <svn_server>/SVN-Repo C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\repo.git
```

Then edit `repo.git/subgit/config` to set

```
trunk = Project1/trunk:refs/heads/project1-master
branches = Project2/trunk:refs/heads/project2-master
branches = Project1/branches/*:refs/heads/project1-*
branches = Project2/branches/*:refs/heads/project2-*
shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
tags = Project1/tags/*:refs/tags/project1-*
tags = Project2/tags/*:refs/tags/project2-*
```

Then run

```
subgit install C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\repo.git
```

Then you can run

```
subgit uninstall C:\GitRepos\SVN-Repo\repo.git
```

if you don't need continuous synchronization.

In this case you have 1 Git repository with branches starting with `project1-` and `project2-` corresponding to your project. Instead of `project1-`/`project2-` you can also use `project1/`/`project2/`.

So depeding on what you need you can choose one of these 3 options but the first one is the best one.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. I keep the option 1.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time conversion of SVN to git, I'd recommend using svn2git. There are many tools with this name. Probably the best is the KDE one at https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. To analyze the SVN repo history upfront for building up proper rules for svn2git, you might use svneverever from here: http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763.

I transformed a couple of SVN repos to Git already with these and does a really great job.

And you can use the `prefix` rule there to get the subdirectory you want.